# how to know the wifi direct commands which used in android?

Tags: android, linux, command, wifi, wifi-direct

i interested to know what commands that used in Android ?
i have a look to p2p WIFI direct but i didn't catch these commands!!

i see these commands from this [link](http://dishingtech.blogspot.com/2012/01/realtek-wi-fi-direct-programming-guide.html)  that used in Linux.

but do they used in android frame-ware ? and if yes how can i access them on rooted device ??

i see that `iwconfig` wireless packages doesn't supported on Android and see links show how to install it!

Comment: Maybe check the [`docs`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)? (first result for a google search of "android wifi direct")

Comment: no !!
i need the linux commands that this API used ?

Comment: I'm certainly curious as to why, but since Android is open source you could poke around [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.java). Although that low-level stuff may be part of the wifi drivers for the device (which are not open-source)

Comment: well i see this link but i can't get what commands that they used to send it to the drivers.
but what do you mean with wifi driver ? is it wireless packages in linux that they used ?